# django paginator is not working but the link is working manually

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I have a page that represents the articles based on categories. I am trying to make a pageinator for this page but I see no pageinator in my webpage. However when I enter the link manually it works. i don't know what I'm missing here...
#my HTML page

```
    <div class="blog-pagination">
          <ul class="justify-content-center">
            {% if cat_articles.has_previous %}
              <li><a
                  href="{% url 'website:category' cat_articles.previous_page_number %}">
                  <i class="icofont-rounded-left"
                     ></i></a></li>
            {% endif %}
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li class="#"><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            {% if cat_articles.has_next %}
          <li><a href="{% url 'website:category' cat_articles.next_page_number %}">
              <i class="icofont-rounded-right"
                 ></i></a></li>
          {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div><!-- End blog entries list -->
```

#my view

```
def category(request, slug, page=1):
cat = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug, status=True)
articles_cat = cat.articles.filter(status='Published')
paginator_cat = Paginator(articles_cat, 1)
cat_articles = paginator_cat.get_page(page)
context = {
    "category": cat_articles
}
return render(request, 'website/category.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Amin Etemadi - My advise is to use ListView. It comes with a simple way to add pagination by adding something like `paginate_by=10`. That's it. And if you need to get articles based on a specific category then simply override the `get_queryset()` for ListView and put your logic there and that's it. In the template you can do something like this

```
{% if is_paginated %}
                        <div class="pagination">
                            <ul >

                                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                                    <li class="page-item">
                                        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}"
                                           aria-label="Previous">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                {% endif %}

                                <li class="page-item active">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.number }}">{{ page_obj.number }}
                                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                                    <li class="page-item">
                                        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}"
                                           aria-label="Next">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                {% endif %}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
```